# VisibleDeprecationWarning:Python in Jupyter

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter, warnings, deprecation-warning

The code below works fine but is written for a two-dimensional array. I want to write it for a one-dimensional array.

```
*def tokenize_and_transform(X, sample_size):
    essays1 = X[:, 0]
    essays2 = X[:, 1]
    tok_es1 = [word_tokenize(doc) for doc in essays1[:sample_size]]
    tok_es2 = [word_tokenize(doc) for doc in essays2[:sample_size]]
    met = MeanEmbeddingTransformer()
    X_transform = np.append(met.fit_transform(tok_es1), met.fit_transform(tok_es2), axis=1)
    return X_transform*
```

The code I want to write is as follows:

```
*def tokenize_and_transform(X, sample_size):
    essays1 = X
    tok_es1 = [word_tokenize(doc) for doc in essays1[:sample_size]]
    met = MeanEmbeddingTransformer()
    X_transform = met.fit_transform(tok_es1)
    return X_transform*
```

However, when I run this code:

```
*X_transform = tokenize_and_transform(X, 4202)*
```

I get an error:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested
> sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays
> with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do
> this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray return
> np.array([self._doc_mean(doc) for doc in X])